# How to keep JSON : in CSV output instead of =>?

Tags: json, ruby, postgresql, csv, ruby-on-rails-4

A `json` field `ui_layout` in `postgres` table needs to be exported to `CSV` in Rails 4.2. The `ui_layout` looks like it in `postgres` table:

```
{"val":"test","val1":"test1","val2":"test2"}
```

The export code is:

```
csv << obj.ui_layout
```

In `CSV`, the `ui_layout` looks as:

```
{"val"=>"test","val1"=>"test1","val2"=>"test2"}
```

The `:` was replaced with `=>`. and this causes problem in following process. It seems that the `ui_layout` was parsed with `JSON.parse(value)` before it was fed to `CSV`as `hash`. What we need to have is to keep the `:` in `CSV` output. Is there a way we can achieve it nicely in Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make `csv << obj.ui_layout` more explicit by doing `csv << obj.ui_layout.to_json`.

EDIT: I'd like to point out that this isn't the most efficient way to deal with it as what's happening is essentially, that the JSON string is being serialized into a hash and then the hash is being turned back into a JSON string. I did do some reading but I'm still not sure of how to make it so ROR doesn't serialize that field. If you could figure that out (or if someone with more knowledge were to comment) it would be more efficient and thus faster.